# Looking for Explanation design or My Confusion

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have created application on My Login Screen. I added 2 EditText Fields.

The Problem or Confusion :

Following code i use for make those EditText

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/username_et"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Output of above code(Sorry i provided Only One Field.) :

[image: Image 1]

I want to Understand what is difference between this and my Code :

Specially Want to know about `Material` and how can i change colour My TextInputLayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="@string/shr_hint_username">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Source of Code : [Click Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-kotlin/#2)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.android.material` is a replacement for old support library as per this post [Revised naming for packages and Maven artifacts](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html)

The mapping for old support library `android.design.**` is the new `com.google.android.material.@`

[Setting up a Material Components theme for Android](https://medium.com/over-engineering/setting-up-a-material-components-theme-for-android-fbf7774da739)

[Material Components Android TextInputLayout](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md)